# Flutter update state coming from another screen

Tags: flutter, setstate

I have two Screens. In the first one, there is a `ListView`. In the first element I display the value of the variable `selectedObject`.

When the `ListTile` is pressed, a second Screen is opened. I want to update the `selectedObject` value after returning from the second screen.

I need to assign the value of `result` to the `selectedObject` variable.

I think I have to call the `setState` method but I don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
class _FilterTaskState extends State<FilterTask> {
List taskList;

String selectedObject = "initial value";

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: _buildAppBar(context, "AppBar Title"),
  body: Center(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
         new ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black),
          title: new Text("Selected Object", style: styleTitle),
          subtitle: new Text(selectedObject),
          trailing: new Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.black),
          onTap: () => _navigateToFilterObject(context),
        ),

        ...

      ],
     )
   ),
  );
 }
}


 _navigateToFilterObject(BuildContext context) async {
    final result = await Navigator.push(context, 
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FilterObject()),);

    /// I want to set the 'selectedObject' value
    /// selectedObject = result;

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On your `FilterObject` widget returns the value when you select the item like this:

```
        Navigator.of(context).pop(theValueYouWantToReceive);
```

And you will get the result inside `result` variable:

```
final result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FilterObject()),);
```

Final code

```
     _navigateToFilterObject(BuildContext context) async {
            final result = await Navigator.push(context, 
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FilterObject()),);
             //refresh the state of your Widget
                 setState(() {
              selectedObject = result;
            });

     }
```

`_navigateToFilterObject` must be inside your `_FilterTaskState` class

Read about Navigator pop :  https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html

Comment: Thanks for your time @diegoveloper. I've already tried exactly that, but I get the error message `The funcion setState isn't defined`

Comment: _navigateToFilterObject function must be inside your State class

Comment: you are totally right...what a stupid mistake...thanks a lot for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: @diegoveloper but what if I don't use push navigator. I just use class constructor to load the screen. Or is there an output for constructor? Usually I just use in for input parameters. `Positioned(
            child: PlaceholderFilter(filterText: '',),
            bottom: 10,
          ),` Then how to refresh setState like from action from PlaceholderFilter?

Comment: it is throwing `setState() called after dispose()` exception